# Are we fish mongers or teachers of angling?

Tags: discussion

In an [excellent answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/2921/70), Gene G provides a deep link into Family Search where an OP can browse images of lists of passengers arriving in Baltimore in the early twentieth century.

If the next immigrant ancestor considered by that OP happened to arrive through New Orleans, then he will need to come back to post a new question asking for Gene or someone else to find the appropriate FS link. Because he (or she) still has no idea how the information provided last time was located.

An alternative approach would be to provide an extended answer on how to filter the list of collections available on *Family Search* so that some of the genealogical expertise evident here can be shared.

Which type of response truly deserves a {Nice Answer} - one that passes on a few snippets of arcane knowledge or one that empowers the questioner to improve her own practice?

Comment: If you are tempted to respond in terms of the number of questions that might be asked under each regime, be aware that I regard that as ABSOLUTELY IRRELEVANT to my question.

Comment: I'd suggest leaving a comment suggesting that Gene G add the search process, or adding it in yourself if you feel up to it. I agree it's best to teach as well as to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I expanded the answer a bit to suggest techniques for fishing in Chesapeake and other bays.

Answer (score 1):

> "Which type of response truly deserves a {Nice Answer}"

Both types do. Teaching someone to fish is valuable and giving someone the fish they need is valuable. I don't believe it's and 'either or' question. Obviously doing both is even better (ie answering the specific problem the OP has while teaching the OP how to do it themselves in the future if they have a similar problem by showing them how you found the information). However there will be many cases when the answerer only does one or the other (answers the problem or teaches how to answer the problem). Both are valuable in their own right.

Comment: Many 'Nice Answers' also come about after a few edits anyways. That said, developing a culture that strives for constant improvement and doesn't settle for mediocrity is a great target to aim for. I think that we all need to get over the fear of stepping on others' toes when it comes to editing and just _do it_ to make the answers or questions better.